# Docker PHP 8.1-apache: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'memcached.so'

Tags: php, docker

I'm completely confused!
I built a docker container:

```
FROM php:8.1-apache
MAINTAINER Ben Jannedy (ben@test.com)

# Set correct timezone
[...]

# Install GD
RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y libfreetype6-dev \
libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
libpng-dev \
libzip-dev \
libicu-dev \
curl \
libonig-dev \
libc-client-dev \
libkrb5-dev \
libmemcached-dev \
git \
libxslt-dev \
msmtp \
mariadb-client \
&& docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg=/usr/include/ \
&& docker-php-ext-install gd \
&& docker-php-ext-install intl \
&& docker-php-ext-install calendar \
&& docker-php-ext-configure imap --with-kerberos --with-imap-ssl \
&& docker-php-ext-install imap \
&& docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo_mysql \
&& docker-php-ext-install gettext \
&& pecl install memcached \
&& docker-php-ext-enable memcached \
&& docker-php-ext-install zip \
&& docker-php-ext-install xsl \
&& apt-get -y remove libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng-dev libzip-dev libicu-dev libonig-dev libc-client-dev libkrb5-dev libmemcached-dev libxslt-dev \
&& apt-get -y autoremove \
&& apt-get -y clean \
&& rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*


COPY htdocs/* /var/www/html/

# Start!
CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

When starting up the container I get the following errors:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'memcached' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/memcached (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/memcached: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/memcached.so (libmemcached.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

Memcached is only an example. This also happens to gd, xls and zip.

Within the container, the directory is available and accessible:

```
root@www:/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902# ls -la
total 2616
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   4096 Feb 18 17:46 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   4096 Feb 17 19:30 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  35264 Feb 18 17:45 calendar.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 423000 Feb 18 17:44 gd.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  18784 Feb 18 17:45 gettext.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 105920 Feb 18 17:45 imap.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 486264 Feb 18 17:45 intl.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 650664 Feb 18 17:45 memcached.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 154752 Feb 18 17:45 mysqli.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 541288 Feb 17 19:30 opcache.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  35424 Feb 18 17:45 pdo_mysql.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  89216 Feb 17 19:30 sodium.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  35776 Feb 18 17:46 xsl.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  72896 Feb 18 17:45 zip.so
```

Does somebody know what's wrong?

Regards,

Ben

Answer (score 0):

You install `libmemcached-dev` which automatically installs `libmemcached11`.

When you remove it again and then do a `apt-get autoremove -y` it also removes `libmemcached11` which is needed by the php memcached extension.

You should install all libs required by your php build manually (or set them to manual) since you're not using packages.

Comment: So that means, when I remove the 'apt-get -y remove' line and the 'apt-get -y autoremove' it should work? I try that out tomorrow. Thanks for the hint! Too tired now - more than 10h of coding... need to sleep first... ZZzzz

Comment: That or you install the dependency manually, e.g. `apt-get install libmemcached11`

Comment: It worked!!! Thanks a lot, z4rp! It caused me headaches and a night of almost no sleep!